# Python Msql Insert using import CSV

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I very new to learning python. *I am unable to get the following code to insert the record in my Mysql database. The insert works in Mysql server, and if I enter the physical data in the query.*

Error code

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_id) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",row)
```

**The following  error is from pycharms.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO 
employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_id) 
VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",row)
```

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

from mysql.connector.abstracts import MySQLCursorAbstract

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database=db
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
with open(r"C:\\data\\LEARNING\\PHYTON\\excel\\MySQL\\texperts\\EMPLOYEES.csv") as csv_data:
    csv_reader =csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=',')
    print(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
       print(row)
       mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_id) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",row)
       print("Record Inserted")
#csv_data.close()
mycursor.execute("commit;")
mycursor.close()
```

I have tried to insert the record directly with mysql workbench and it worked.

```
INSERT INTO texperts.EMPLOYEE(EMP_id, emp_init, First_name, last_name, email, phone, role_ID) VALUES("1","JD","Janet","Delton","JDelton@roger.ca","4037407004","4");
```

I also tried to the following and it worked from pyton.

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO texperts.EMPLOYEE(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_ID) VALUES(1,'JD','Janet','Delton','JDelthon@roger','403-740-7004',4);")
```

I have tried differnt varition of row, (row), (row[0],row[1]..row[6])  at the end of the following script. *

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email,   phone, role_id) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",row)
```

Comment: Try unpacking `row` using `*` like this: `*row` or passing as `tuple(row)`. Also, maybe the problem is that `row` is list containing only strings but you have to convert some of them to numbers so that they match column types.

Comment: How do you change the Emp_ID  and role_id from the "1"  & "4"  to 1  & 4,  by INT(Row[0]....  INT(Row[6]??   I have already tried  Tuple(row), but will try again tonight.  thanks again.

Comment: You don't want `VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')`. You want: `VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the modified code with your code, it worked fine for me.

**Code** :

> ```py
>  import mysql.connector 
>  import csv 
>  import os
>
> def main():
>     file_path = "C:/data/LEARNING/PYTHON/excel/MYSQL/texperts/EMPLOYEES.csv"
>     if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
>         print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
>         return
>
>     mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
>         host="localhost",
>         user="root",
>         password="<password>",
>         database="texperts"
>     )
>
>     mycursor = mydb.cursor()
>
>     with open(file_path) as csv_data:
>         csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=',')
>         print("Contents of csv_reader:")
>         print(csv_reader)
>         next(csv_reader)  
>         for row in csv_reader:
>             print("Contents of row:")
>             print(row)
>             sql = "INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
>             mycursor.execute(sql, row)
>             print("Record Inserted")
>
>     mydb.commit()
>     mycursor.close()
>     mydb.close()
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     main()
> ```

**EMPLOYEES.csv :**

```
emp_id,emp_init,first_name,last_name,email,phone,role_id
1,JD,John,Doe,johndoe@example.com,1234567890,1
2,AL,Alice,Lee,alicelee@example.com,0987654321,2
3,BT,Bob,Smith,bobsmith@example.com,1112223333,3
```

**Output** :

```py
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Documents\xxxxxxxx\src\main.py 
Contents of csv_reader:
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000021246C021C0>
Contents of row:
['1', 'JD', 'John', 'Doe', 'johndoe@example.com', '1234567890', '1']
Record Inserted
Contents of row:
['2', 'AL', 'Alice', 'Lee', 'alicelee@example.com', '0987654321', '2']
Record Inserted
Contents of row:
['3', 'BT', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'bobsmith@example.com', '1112223333', '3']
Record Inserted
```

Comment: Maybe it would be usefull if you explain what the problem the PO had with the cuotation marks and the placeholders. That will help him to learn and not doing it again

Comment: I believe it's the variable %s that is not being accepted sql="INSERT INTO employee(emp_id, emp_init, first_name, last_name, email, phone, role_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
 mycursor.execute(sql, row)    raise get_exception(packet)    
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1

Comment: What values do you have in your `row` variable? Can you do a print(row)? the %s is not a variable, it is a placeholder and it is accepted in the mysql cursor

Comment: I have placed a comma right before the first %s.  As you can see the placeholder %s now have transferred the first row of the file.  The first and last columns are numbers, but they are in quotes and this will make it 7 columns.     VALUES (,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"  Error1064  42000MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ','1', 'JD', 'Janet', 'Delton', 'JDelton@roger.ca', '403-740-7004', '4')' at line 1   mycursor.execute(sql, row) now is failing with the placeholder variables. Msql 8.0, Python 3.8.1, Windows 11, pycharm 2020.2.3 community edition

Comment: Remove that first comma before the first placeholder

Comment: Finally, the issue was solved. I can't explain it yet.  I used (prepared=True) with the mycursor = mydb.cursor() and used  question mark  ? instead of the %s.     I want to thank all you that gave suggestions.  I came across another note on StackOverflow that says some database only accept the ? while other %s.   
/ See the following note using variable %s and ?.    [link ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html) _italic_ **bold**